# transformation and functions of random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, self-learning

Let $X,Y$ be independent random variables. I already have the distribution of $XY$ over a certain subinterval of $\mathbb{R}$, by convolution. My question is, is it possible to get the distribution of $X(c-Y)$ without solving for the entire thing again?

Are there any theorems that will allow me to have a result without solving for the entire thing again?